# Flex Event Blocked by Another Object

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, event-handling, events, mxml

I am using a box element to add a transparent overlay to a column of buttons. I want to add a click event to the buttons. However, when you click a button the click event is only triggered on the overlaying box. **Is there anyway to pass the event to the underlying button or perhaps a better way to display an overlay without blocking the click event?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a DisplayObject (which nearly all visual things subclass in Flex) to be treated as "transparent" to the mouse (i.e. it won't intercept click events), set that object's mouseEnabled property to false.

e.g.

```
transparentBox.mouseEnabled = false;
```